# MS Word Mail-Merge using SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, ms-word

Is it possible to import data from an SQLite database in order to use Word's Mail Merge feature?

Is there a different Database which Word supports and is easy to read/write to with C#?

Answer (score 1):

"Word's mail merge feature lets you use a wide variety of data sources. Supported data sources include Excel spreadsheets, Access databases, SQL Server databases."

Unfortunately, I haven't found anything related to the usage of SQLite database with Word Merge Feature.

For detailed information: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-do-i-use-microsoft-words-mail-merge-feature/6048153

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, however Word Mail Merges can be done with an ODBC connection, there is an ODBC driver for SQLite [here](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/)

Comment: Do you also know how to use such a driver? If not that's fine, I'll probably find it somewhere. Thank you!

Comment: I don't, but I've used ODBC in the past for mail merges, generally it's install the driver, and then when in the mail merge for selecting the recipients you select "new source" (it's under browse in Word 2010), and then you can generally follow through the wizard, selecting your db, and what tables you want etc.

Comment: hmm I get an error when I do that. "Unable to obtain list of tables from the data source"

Comment: Just tried installing it and getting the same issue. It looks like it works in excel using it as a Microsoft Query Datasource.. which would mean you'd need to use Excel as an intermediary, depends on how often you need to do the merge.  MS Access might be a better bet in this scenario for your datasource.  It just depends what will be quicker for you in the long run. Whether re setting up the database in Access, or just refreshing the data in the excel spreadsheet before the mailmerge is run. (Word may do this automatically but I'm not sure).

Comment: It would be better if there weren't any steps in between. The whole process should be automated using C#, and that as easy as possible :) So I think Excel would overcomplicate things, but thanks for that anyway!